# R - Inside function check if object exists

Tags: r, function, missing-data, exists

I have four functions:

```
f1 <- function(x){if(exists(x)){return(2*x)}}
f2 <- function(x){if(exists("x")){return(2*x)}}
f3 <- function(x){if(!missing(x)){return(2*x)}}
f4 <- function(x){if(!missing("x")){return(2*x)}}
```

However, `exists` and `missing` doesn't work properly for any of the formats above and I receive the following error messages:

```
f1(x)
Error in exists(x) : object 'x' not found
f2(x)
Error in f2(x) : object 'x' not found
f3(x)
Error in f3(x) : object 'x' not found
f4(x)
Error in f4(x) : object 'x' not found
```

Is there any way to fix the functions to not crash when `x` is not defined?

Comment: Are you trying check if the _value_ of `x` is NA or if the _parameter_ itself exists (was provided when the function is called)?

Comment: I would like the function does nothing (or simply print a message that `x` is not defined) when someone calls `f(x)` if `x` is not defined! Basically, I'd like to stop my code from crasheing if `f(x)` is called and `x` has not yet been defined!

Comment: I think it might be a little bit confusing that you are referring to the parameter `x` and the object `x` (that's being passed) interchangeably. Correct me if I'm wrong. What you want is to check if any arbitrary object being passed in exists, but not the parameter `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The R interpreter evaluates first the line `f(x)` and then what is in the function. The interpreter finds an unknown element `x` and stops immediately evaluating the rest of the code.

Therefore, it won't work in any scenario you've given, as the problem comes before the function evaluation.

You have to put your check outside the function:

```
if(exists("x")) {
    f(x)
}
```

Or, depending on your needs, you can do:

```
f <- function(x) {
    if(!missing("x")) { return(x * 2) }
}

f() // do nothing
f(2) // return 4
```

Comment: Your first sentence is not quite right! If I define a function as `f <- function(x){cat("Function started...");if(exists("x")){2*x}}` and run it for an undefined `x`; it still goes inside the function and runs it and prints the message `"Function started..."`. Here is the output: `Function started...Error in f(x) : object 'x' not found`

Comment: The first method is fine if we know beforehand the variable name that is going to be passed onto `f`, but not if we want `f` to dynamically check if the object being passed in exists from the environment in which it was called. The second method simply doesn't work if the object doesn't exist.

Comment: Indeed, you are right. This is because the arguments are evaluated lazily, as explained [here](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~statcur/Workshop2/Presentations/functions.pdf) in the slides 9 and 10

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to check if an object exists in the global environment inside a function, but what we are interested, is not the value of `x`, but the object being passed onto `x` when the function is called. Here is where we can use `enquo` from `rlang` to turn the expression being passed in to a quosure, and `quo_name` turns it into a string:

```
library(rlang)

f1 <- function(x){ 
  arg <- quo_name(enquo(x))
  if(exists(arg, where = .GlobalEnv)){
    return(2*x)
  } else {
    cat('variable ', '`', arg, '`', ' does not exist', sep = "")
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
> x <- 2
> f1(x)
[1] 4

> f1(y)
variable `y` does not exist
```

Assuming `y` does not exist.

Comment: When I run your code on my machine, here is what I get: `f(2)` 
`variable '2' does not exist`
`f(x)`
`Error in f(x) : object 'x' not found`

Comment: @Mahmoud I've added a `where` argument to `exists` which should fix the second case, for the first case, it's because it's checking for an object named `2` in your global environment, which doesn't exist. If you assign `2` to `x` then run `f(x)`, it works.