# R: How to check whether object exists inside function?

Tags: r, function, object, exists

**Question**

I need to check whether an object exists *inside* a function and not elsewhere. How can I do this?

To make clear what I mean I use `exists`:

```
fun <- function(){exists("x")}
x <- 1
fun()
> TRUE
```

My expected output for the code above is `FALSE` because the variable `x` was created *outside* the function. So `x` is saved inside the global environment and that is why the funtion returns `TRUE` but can we somehow test whether `x` is in `"function environment"`?

---

**I've tried**

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57081877/r-inside-function-check-if-object-exists) which also does not work in my case. There they suggest using

```
library(rlang)

f1 <- function(x){ 
  arg <- quo_name(enquo(x))
  if(exists(arg, where = .GlobalEnv)){
    return(2*x)
  } else {
    cat('variable ', '`', arg, '`', ' does not exist', sep = "")
  }
}
```

I expect the output being `variable x does not exist` for both following cases but this is not the case if `x` was defined *outside* the function before:

```
x <- 1
f1(x)
> 2

rm(x)
f1(x)
variable `x` does not exist
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can do this by specifying a specific environment for `exists` to search in and tell it to *only* look there, and not in the enclosing environments.

The `where=` argument tells `exists` where to look for that object. We can either specify it explicitly with `environment()` (which returns the current environment), or use the default value of `-1` which drops the `R_GlobalEnv` from the list of environments to search.

Either way, the key is to set `inherits=FALSE` to limit it to *only* the specified environment. Otherwise, it also looks in the enclosing environments (like `R_GlobalEnv`) which we don't want:

```
x <- 1
fun <- function(){exists("x", inherits = F)}

fun()
[1] FALSE
```

However if we define x in the enviroment of the function, it returns TRUE:

```
fun <- function(){
    x<-3;
    exists("x", inherits = F)}
fun()
[1] TRUE
```

The example mentioned with explicitly defined environment:

```
fun <- function(){exists("x", where = environment(), inherits = F)}
```

---

What's happening with the default `where=-1` argument? The documentation says that if you provide it with an integer, it selects the environment based on "the position in the search list". We can see that `.GlobalEnv` is at position 1, followed by attached packages

```
rm(list=ls()) # clear .GlobalEnv
x <- 3  # Add x to .GlobalEnv
ls()    # Show that x is the only thing in .GlobalEnv
[1] "x"

search() # Show the search list
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:lubridate" "package:forcats"   "package:stringr"  
 [5] "package:dplyr"     "package:purrr"     "package:readr"     "package:tidyr"    
 [9] "package:tibble"    "package:ggplot2"   "package:tidyverse" "tools:rstudio"    
[13] "package:stats"     "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" "package:utils"    
[17] "package:datasets"  "package:methods"   "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```

Now we run this function which checks for different objects in different environments by integer value:

```
fun <- function(){
    y <- 3
    k <- function(){
        z <- 3
        print(exists('z', -1, inherit=FALSE))
        print(exists('x', 1, inherit=FALSE))
        print(exists('y', parent.frame(), inherit=FALSE))}
    k()
    print(exists('x', -1, inherit=FALSE))
    print(exists('y', -1, inherit=FALSE))
    print(exists('x', 1, inherit=FALSE))
    print(exists('ymd', 2, inherit=FALSE))
    print(exists('last2', 3, inherit=FALSE))
    print(exists('str_detect', 4, inherit=FALSE))
}

> fun()
[1] TRUE   # Inside k(), -1 is the function env for k() - z is there
[1] TRUE   # 1 is .GlobalEnv, x is there
[1] TRUE   # to choose parent env with y, we need to specify it with parent.frame()
[1] FALSE  # -1 is the function env, x not in function env
[1] TRUE   # -1 is the function env, y is in function env
[1] TRUE   # 1 is .GlobalEnv, x is in .GlobalEnv
[1] TRUE   # position 2 is the lubridate package
[1] TRUE   # position 3 is the forcats package
[1] TRUE   # position 4 is the stringr package
```

From this we can see that `-1` is always the local environment  of the current function, while 1 is .GlobalEnv and higher numbers are attached packages as listed by `search()`. If you want to specify with more detail, for instance to look in `fun()` from within `k()`, then you need to specify the environment explicitly, either with a relative function like `parent.frame()` as above or by getting the environment as an object and referring directly as below:

```
fun <- function(){
    y <- 3
    env <- environment()
    k <- function(e){
        z <- 3
        print(exists('y', inherit=FALSE))
        print(exists('y', where=e, inherit=FALSE))
        }
    k(env)
}
fun()
[1] FALSE
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Default `where` is fine for this question, you can just do `inherits = FALSE` only

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Very true. Is this always safe - will `-1` always give the environment of the enclosing function?

Comment: I assume so, I was thinking it worked like `which` in sys.frame. But looking at `?exists` now, doesn't seem to say anything about it.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Yeah, I was a bit confused by that. It says that an integer refers to "the position in the search list", and that makes sense for values >=1 (it looks in the environments of the attached package as listed in `search()`), but there's no mention of `-1` there. I think that must be a special meaning for -1: the current function's local environment. But I can't find a reference for that

Comment: @divibisan you'll find the reference in the docs for `as.environment`

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use `ls`:

```r
f1 <- function() { "x" %in% ls() }

f2 <- function() { x <- 1; "x" %in% ls() }

x <- 1

f1()
#> [1] FALSE
f2()
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>