# How to check if dataframe exists while using a scheduler which calls a function

Tags: r, exists

I try to run a scheduler every second which calls a function.
Within the function a dataframe is generated in the first iteration from the scheduler.
In the next iteration I would like to generate a new dataframe and bind_row it with the inital dataframe.
I do not succeed since the function does not recognize the dataframe in memory.
See the example code below which does not bind_row the dataframes.

I have also tried to implement the function f1 from:
[R: How to check whether object exists inside function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70992780/r-how-to-check-whether-object-exists-inside-function)
Although this gave the same issue.

I suppose I do have to check a specific place in memory where R saves objects from within a function although I do not succeed.

Any idea how I can solve this?

Thank you!

```
library(tcltk2)

# alternative 1

run_once <- function() {

  # Create a data frame
  mydf1 <- data.frame (
    Fruit = c("apple", "pear"),
    Price = c(60, 45)
  )
  
  if (exists("mydf1_all", inherits = F) == TRUE){
    mydf1_all <- bind_rows(mydf1_all, mydf1)
    print("rows binded")
  } else {
    mydf1_all <- mydf1
    print("rows not binded")
  }

  print(Sys.time())
  
  # output run_once functie:
  mydf1_all_output <<- mydf1_all
  return(mydf1_all_output)
  }

# start scheduler:
tclTaskSchedule(1000, run_once(), id = "run_once", redo = TRUE)

# stop scheduler:
tclTaskDelete("run_once")


# alternative 2

run_once2 <- function() {
  
  # Create a data frame
  mydf1 <- data.frame (
    Fruit = c("apple", "pear"),
    Price = c(60, 45)
  )
  
  
  if (exists("mydf1_all") && is.data.frame(get("mydf1_all")) == TRUE){
    mydf1_all <- bind_rows(mydf1_all, mydf1)
    print("rows binded")
  } else {
    mydf1_all <- mydf1
    print("rows not binded")
  }
  
  print(Sys.time())
  
  # output run_once functie:
  mydf1_all_output <<- mydf1_all
  return(mydf1_all_output)
}

# start scheduler:
tclTaskSchedule(1000, run_once2(), id = "run_once2", redo = TRUE)

# stop scheduler:
tclTaskDelete("run_once2")
```

Comment: As you've noticed this does not work, since the rerunning the function will create a new, distinct execution environment. — Functions such as `exists` are generally almost never what you want: as the author of the code you should *know* whether a variable exists, there should never be any need to *check* this in code (`exists` is a low-level tool for metaprogramming). As a matter of fact you might want to use a [closure](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html?q=closure#first-class-functions) here. But more fundamentally I suspect the logic needs rethinking.

Comment: Unrelatedly, writing `== TRUE` makes no sense, it is completely tautological. Simply remove it.

Comment: @ Konrad Rudolph Thank you for your explanation. Good argument regarding exists. If I read paragraph 7.4.4. I noticed there is a method mentioned at the end of the paragraph with a function in a function (plus_one). Is this what you mean with using a closure? Regarding rethinking the logic. I suppose I am pretty bound to using a scheduler, if I would like to run a proces once a second, as far as I have researched. The scheduler needs a function if I am correct.

Comment: You have `mydf1_all_output <<- mydf1_all` without defining `mydf1_all_output` in advance.  That's a bad idea.  It messes with the global environment.  In the distant future, you might have a variable with that name in your workspace for a completely different reason; this would wipe it out.

Comment: @KonradRudolph `x == TRUE` is tautological in programming terms, but can make code more readable because it helps readers understand that `x` is a logical value/vector. It's not a big deal but in any case, `if(x == TRUE)` doesn't do any harm relative to `if(x)`, does it?

Comment: @MattAshby “but it can make the code more readable” — Categorically no. Why would it? … the “harm” is that it adds clutter: added characters devoid of information that  detract from actually relevant code. It’s a tiny difference for a single instance, of course. But it compounds over the entire code base, and it is an utterly one-sided calculus: slight quality decrease, zero benefit.

Comment: @user2165379 I am referring to the linked paragraph: 6.2.3. The relevant usage of the term “closure” occurs in the 4th subsequent paragraph, and should even be highlighted. What it means that the function can carry *state*, i.e. refer to variables that are not reset when the function is rerun. However, you’re right: section 7.4.4 also contains relevant information about the executing environment.

Comment: @ Konrad Rudolph Thanks. I see that my problem is the same as in paragraph 6.4.3. The solution is mentioned to be in paragraph 10.2.4. with stateful functions and function factories. I will try to implement this and let you know the outcome.

Comment: @ Konrad Rudolph Thanks Konrad, I did succeed to implement the solution and posted the code in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your clues and advice. I have implemented these in the code below and it is running fine now. If you have any idea for a fundamentally different logic, I still will be interested!

```
library(tcltk2)
library(dplyr)

# alternative 1

run_once <- function() {

  # Create a data frame
  mydf1 <- data.frame (
    Fruit = c("apple", "pear"),
    Price = c(60, 45)
  )
  
  if (exists("mydf1_all")){
    mydf1_all <<- bind_rows(mydf1_all, mydf1)
    print("rows binded")
  } else {
    mydf1_all <<- mydf1
    print("rows not binded")
  }

  print(Sys.time())
  
  # output run_once function:
  return(mydf1_all)
  }

# start scheduler:
tclTaskSchedule(1000, run_once(), id = "run_once", redo = TRUE)

# stop scheduler:
tclTaskDelete("run_once")


# alternative 2

run_once2 <- function() {
  
  # Create a data frame
  mydf1 <- data.frame (
    Fruit = c("apple", "pear"),
    Price = c(60, 45)
  )
  
  
  if (exists("mydf1_all") && is.data.frame(get("mydf1_all"))){
    mydf1_all <<- bind_rows(mydf1_all, mydf1)
    print("rows binded")
  } else {
    mydf1_all <<- mydf1
    print("rows not binded")
  }
  
  print(Sys.time())
  
  # output run_once function:
  return(mydf1_all)
}

# start scheduler:
tclTaskSchedule(1000, run_once2(), id = "run_once2", redo = TRUE)

# stop scheduler:
tclTaskDelete("run_once2")
```